# How to return specific properties of objects in form of array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes an array of dog objects and returns an array of the specific properties

```
The code that I have tried
function Owner(dogs) {
     dogs.map(value => {
     if (value.breed === 'GermanShepherd') {
         return value.owner;    
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using `reduce()` and check if the breed if same with `search` variable, if it is, use `concat()` to add to the accumulator.

```js
let arr = [{"name":"Beatrice","breed":"Lurcher","owner":"Tom"},{"name":"Max","breed":"GermanShepherd","owner":"Malcolm"},{"name":"Poppy","breed":"GermanShepherd","owner":"Vikram"}];
let search = 'GermanShepherd';

let result = arr.reduce((c, v) => v.breed === search ? c.concat(v.owner) : c, []);

console.log(result);
```

---

You can also use `filter` and `map` combo.

```js
let arr = [{"name":"Beatrice","breed":"Lurcher","owner":"Tom"},{"name":"Max","breed":"GermanShepherd","owner":"Malcolm"},{"name":"Poppy","breed":"GermanShepherd","owner":"Vikram"}]
let search = 'GermanShepherd';

let result = arr.filter(o => o.breed === search).map(o => o.owner);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @Eddie Approach two is definetly are efficient and readable solution